# ifDefine varOne | varTwo

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, ifdefine

Is something to the effect of this possible without nesting in a htaccess file?

```
<ifDefine !development | !staging>
    ....
```

Ideally I would use an environment variable but this is not possible in this case.

Comment: It depends what you want to do inside `if` condition.

Comment: rewritecond/rewriterule

Comment: `Ideally I would use an environment variable`: Where you set this env variable?

Comment: env vars are set in the virtual host config for dev/production servers, which i understand are not passed to htaccess before it runs.  I could set it inside of htaccess on the condition of the URL or similar, but i'd prefer it to do it as above so this rule can be independent of whatever that condition would be.

Happy to nest the above, but was just wondering if it could be done inline.

Comment: Many things are possible but you need to provide some intended rules here in order to build an answer.